# What does this C function mean ? A function pointer?

Tags: c, function

I would like to know what this C function exactly mean ?

`typedef uint32_t   (*test)     ( void );`

Comment: It is a typdef of a function pointer to a function that takes no args and returns a uint32. So not an actual function pointer but an alias for that type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It basically reads as:

```
                     test                  -- test is
typedef              test                  -- a typedef name (alias) for the type
typedef             *test                  -- pointer to
typedef            (*test)     (      )    --   a function taking
typedef            (*test)     ( void )    --     no parameters
typedef uint32_t   (*test)     ( void );   --   returning uint32_t
```

So `test` is an *alias* for the type "pointer to a function taking no parameters and returning `uint32_t` (`uint32_t (*)(void)`).

So if you had a function like

```
uint32_t foo(void) { return some_value; }
```

then you could create a pointer to that function using either

```
uint32_t (*ptr)(void) = foo;
```

or

```
test ptr = foo;
```

As a matter of style, it's usually a bad idea to hide the pointer-ness of a type in a `typedef`<sup>1</sup>; it would be better to create a typedef like

```
typedef uint32_t test(void); // test is a typedef name for "function taking no parameters
                             // and returning uint32_t
```

and then create the pointer as

```
test *ptr;
```

---

1. Unless you're prepared to write a complete abstraction layer that handles all the pointer operations and hides them from the user, in which case go nuts.

Comment: Thanks! That was great explanation!

Answer (score 3):

It is a typdef of a function pointer to a function that takes no args and returns a uint32. So not an actual function pointer but an alias for that type.

An example of how to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t   (*test)     ( void );

uint32_t my_test1(void)
{
    return 100;
}

// Output of this program will be: 100
int main (void)
{
    test func = my_test1;
    printf("%d\n", func());
}
```